# Newsyslog is not automatically rolling over my log files

Tags: shell, unix, freebsd, syslog

I have configured my log in newsyslog.conf in the following way:

```
/var/log/test.log 644 10 10 * Z /var/run/parser.pid 31
```

And my understanding from man newsyslog.conf is that the 4th field is for size at which to roll over the file in kilobytes. But even though the size of my file crosses that it doesn't seem to roll over automatically.

However if I manually run

```
/etc/rc.d/newsyslog restart
```

the roll over seems to happen without my pid is not getting signalled. I'm really confused now - what's happening here? Why would roll over happen when i restart newsyslog but not automatically - am I missing something here? And why is that restart triggered roll over not signalling the pid?

I'm using freebsd, and my newsyslog configuration is in a custom file within the /etc/newsyslog.d/ directory.

Comment: Is the size mentioned in the manual wrong by an order of 10 i wonder?

Comment: According to [This page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=newsyslog.conf&sektion=5), it's the **5th** column that determines the rollover interval, which, as you've specified `*` means it doesn't rotate based on size.